# Store Input File Selected in Redux to Upload Later

Tags: html, reactjs, file-upload, redux

I have an input with type file as a React component. This is part of a multi-page form. So for text fields in the form I store the data in Redux so that at the end I can upload all the data at the very end.

This will work fine for the text fields. But for an input where it takes in a file I don't see how this can work.

How can I store the file selected in Redux so that at the end I can upload it as part of the data at the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the file in the same way your store other text fields. [The `value` attribute of a `input` of type `file` contains the path of the file saved as string.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file) This value can be saved in the Redux store as a string field.

When you finally process the `form` inputs you can use this value to load and send the file to the server. As per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data)

> Sending files with HTML forms is a special case. Files are binary data — or considered as such — whereas all other data is text data. Because HTTP is a text protocol, there are special requirements for handling binary data.
>
> **The `enctype` attribute** This attribute lets you specify the value of the
>   `Content-Type` HTTP header included in the request generated when the
>   form is submitted. This header is very important because it tells the
>   server what kind of data is being sent. By default, its value is
>   `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. In human terms, this means: "This
>   is form data that has been encoded into URL parameters."
>
> If you want to send files, you need to take three extra steps:
>
> 1. Set the `method` attribute to `POST` because file content can't be put inside URL parameters.
> 2. Set the value of `enctype` to `multipart/form-data`
>      because the data will be split into multiple parts, one for each file
>      plus one for the text data included in the form body (if text is also
>      entered into the form).
> 3. Include one or more `File picker` widgets to
>      allow your users to select the file(s) that will be uploaded.